# Project quick fix shortcut not displaying all options in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I had a hardcoded string in a layout file. As per the [**Android Studio shortcut list**](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html), **Option + Enter** is used for displaying Project quick fixes available for Mac. [**These**](http://envyandroid.com/android-studio-extract-strings-resources/) are the options which should actually appear but this is all I am getting (I hovered on `android:contentDescription="background image"`):

[image]

And the options are never consistent, i.e. they keep on changing like these :

[image]

---

And

---

[image]

But I never get the option to extract the string resource as mentioned in the second link (and as below) :

[image]

Comment: you question says it all. "displays quick fixes available" :) So that maybe the action you wanted to perform has only this option available.

Comment: @Umair : Is it so ? :) I am very sure that is not the case.

Comment: can you tell what exactly you want to do here ?

Comment: @Umair : Replace the hardcoded string with string resource.

Comment: ok it happens sometimes but when i click two or three times then it displays the correct options. And yes that maybe the bug in android studio.

Comment: @Umair : Trouble is, I am never getting the option to **extract string resource**. And yes, the options are not consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To guarantee that this works every time, you should ensure that you place the text cursor inside the string before you press `option` + `enter`

Follow these steps --

1. Place the text cursor inside the string by positioning or clicking the string until you see the blinking cursor between the string

[image]

2. Press `option` + `enter`. This is guaranteed to work every time

[image]

Comment: I think it is quite obvious that the cursor needs to be on the string. The above does not work.

Comment: The cursor I'm talking about refers to the text cursor. Rather than hovering the cursor on the string as you described in the question, it should actually be placed within the actual string for this to work. Check the position of the text cursor in the illustration of the first picture.

Comment: Apologies. I misunderstood. Now it works. As per StackOverFlow, will award the bounty in 22 hours. Thanks.

Comment: No worries. Glad to have helped and clear the confusion. Cheers!